# How to commit a file directly into GitHub from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to commit a file directly into GitHub from VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Install Git:**
   Ensure that Git is installed on your machine. You can download it from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/).
2. **Install GitHub Extension for Visual Studio Code:**
   Install the GitHub extension for Visual Studio Code. You can find it in the Extensions view (`Ctrl+Shift+X`), search for "GitHub", and install the one provided by GitHub.
3. **Sign in to GitHub:**
   Open Visual Studio Code, and sign in to your GitHub account using the GitHub extension.
4. **Initialize a Git Repository:**
   If your project is not already a Git repository, you can initialize one. Open the terminal in Visual Studio Code (`Ctrl+``) and run the following commands:
   git init
5. **Stage Changes:**
   Open the source code file you want to commit. You will see the source control icon in the sidebar. Click on it to open the Source Control view.

   Hover over the file you want to commit, and click the `+` icon to stage the changes.
6. **Commit Changes:**
   Enter a commit message in the input box at the top of the Source Control view and press to commit the changes.
7. **Push Changes to GitHub:**
   After committing the changes, you need to push them to GitHub. Click on the three dots (`...`) in the Source Control view and select "Push".

   Choose the branch you want to push and click "OK".

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541) did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?